# getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sPhotos' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I wrote a PHP script to communicate to MySQL. And I am trying to get all photos in the table.
But It keep throwing me this parse code

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sPhotos' (T_VARIABLE)" on this statement below:

```
$sPhotos = $GLOBALS['CPhotos']->getAllPhotos();
```

I am a lost I'm not missing any semi-colons and I have CPhotos in the script as

```
require_once 'php/CPhotos';
```

Am I calling the function getAllPhotos wrong?

All lines of code above 
    $sPhotos = $GLOBALS['CPhotos']->getAllPhotos();
line.

```
<?php 
   require_once 'php/CMySQL.php';
   require_once 'php/CMembers.php';
   require_once 'php/CPhotos.php';

    // get login data
    list ($sLoginMenu, $sExtra) = $GLOBALS['CMembers']->getLoginData();

    // get all photos
     $sPhotos = $GLOBALS['CPhotos']->getAllPhotos();
```

Comment: Please show the code above this line!

Comment: That usually means a missing bracket or semicolon somewhere

Comment: As shown in your error, could be missing `;` right above this line. Show what content you have before this line

Comment: Please reference this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php  Also, you should STRONGLY consider using an IDE that highlights such syntax errors for you.  Voting to close as the problem here is undoubtedly a simple syntax error.